# Работа с Ajax в Symfony

Tags: php, ajax, symfony3, php7.2

Дает 302 статус, но состояние базы не меняет, а если просто перехожу по ссылке, /subscribe, то добавляет запись и удаляет.

```
<?php

namespace WoolfBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use WoolfBundle\Entity\Subscribe;

class SubscribeController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')")
 * @Route("/subscribe", name="subscribe")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function subscribeAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('WoolfBundle:Subscribe');
    $userEmail = $this->getUser()->getEmail();
    $subscribe = $repository->findOneByEmail($userEmail);

    if(!$subscribe){
        $subscribe = new Subscribe();
        $subscribe->setEmail($this->getUser()->getEmail());
        $em->persist($subscribe);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(true);
    } else {
        $em->remove($subscribe);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(false);
    }
}
}
```

JS файл

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.subscribe', function () {
that = $(this);
$.ajax({
  url:"/subscribe",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    "success": "You are subscribe!"
  },
  async: true,
  success: function (data)
  {
    console.log(data);
    $('div#ajax-results').html(data.success);
  }
});

return false;
});
```

и сам HTML код

```
<button class="subscribe">click me!</button>
<div id="ajax-results"></div>
```

[image: вывод в консль]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: network]

Comment: Судя по скрину консоли, ваш POST запрос не авторизован. 
Гляньте на вкладке network содержит ли запрос куки.

Comment: Вроде нету...Добавил еще один скрин в вопрос

Comment: Да, проблема с /login...Попробовал добавить базовую аутентификацию.То всё выходит

Comment: Загляните в этот топик https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie

Comment: `> если просто перехожу по ссылке, /subscribe, то добавляет запись и удаляет`

Это тоже странно: @Method({"POST"}) разрешает обращаться к этому ресурсу только POST запросом, если вы переходите по ссылке в браузере, браузер отправит GET запрос и результатом должен быть ответ 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: На всякий случай уточню: аннотация `@Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')")` к `/subscribe` добавлена сознательно? Если да, то пользователь должен быть авторизован до выполнения этого запроса.

Comment: ДА, сознательно.Ну было бы не логично подписываться если ты не залогинен...Если что, то решил проблему с помощью FOSJsRoutingBundle

Comment: Если знаешь более подробный ответ на этот вопрос, то напиши и я отмечу

Comment: Код из вашего примера у меня работает без описываемых проблем. Если глянете url запросов /login и /subscribe, то скорее всего обнаружите что они отличаются доменом. То что, подключение бандла с роутингом решает проблему - тому явное свидетельство. На ваших скринах, к сожалению нет полезной информации. Ваш запрос не содержит сессионной куки и причиной тому обычно является кросс-доменный запрос либо ограниченный path в куки .

Answer (score 0):

Эту проблему можно решить FOSJsRoutingBundle

> composer require friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle

потом подключить в app/AppKernel.php

```
new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
```

добавить в app/config/routing.yml

```
fos_js_routing:
resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
```

и выполнить команду

> ## Для Symfony 2
>
> $ php app/console assets:install --symlink web
>
> ## Для Symfony 3
>
> $ php bin/console assets:install --symlink web

Вся документация по этому бандлу есть на сайте Symfony https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html